Is there a way to have both manual data entry and keep the excel query updating when new files are added to the source
I have a excel power query table listing all the files in a folder and i want to have both a column for manual data entry and have it automatically update. I have created the column for manual data entry according to the video down below and that works but now it doesnt update when new files are added to the source folder
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DQRg5PGNmLA0&ved=2ahUKEwiBo-GEmLCGAxVDGBAIHQeDAH4QwqsBegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw0ntETiP_yAEw3MXPS2FzJw
I tried updating every different query but doesnt help

Could you put everything that's required to answer the question in the question please.  Not many people will sit and watch a youtube video to figure out what you need, or to guess at where you went wrong if the video explanation works.

The problem is now that i did as described in the video to be able to have manual data entry in power query, the file lost the ability to update. The query is basically referencing it self to make the manual data possible. I could return tomorrow with my code. Thank you


Create a table "ManualEntries" in the Excel sheet. The column names must be a subset or equal to the ones you get from the folder query.

Have two queries in PQ - Query1 for the ManualEntries table and Query2 for the folder list.

Create a new Appended query (Append as New) from Query1 and Query2 and load just this one. Query1 and Query2 should not be loaded.


Now when you update the ManualEntries table or the folder the Appended query will show rows from both upon refresh.

Yes thank you for answering, the problem seems to be that the loaded quary dont pickup all the info from the appended query. Only the first column is right but all other columns just say null. And i am not able to load those files into the table. They dont appear when i update. Thank you
